# $P(x+2)=2x^3-4x^2+2x+3$. Find the remainder of $\dfrac{P(x)}{(x-3)}$

Tags: polynomials

$P(x+2)=2x^3-4x^2+2x+3$. Find the remainder of $\dfrac{P(x)}{x-3}$
I've tried this: $P(x)=2(x-2)^3-4(x-2)^2+2(x-2)+3$. What should I do next?

Comment: What does $P(u)=2(x-2)^3-4(x-2)^2+2(x-2)+3$ mean? Do you want the remainder of  $P(x)/x-3=\frac{P(x)}{x}-3$ or of  $P(x)/(x-3)=\frac{P(x)}{x-3}$

Comment: Why don't you just set $x=1$ in $P(x+2)=2x^3-4x^2+2x+3$ and get $P(3)=2-4+2+3=3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of viewing this polynomial is

$$
p(x) = 2(x-3)^3 + 2(x-3)^2 + 3
$$

Think you can handle it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$P(x) = 2(x-2)^3 - 4(x-2)^2 + 2(x-2) + 3 \Rightarrow P(3) = 3$, which is the remainder.